# How to programmatically fetch img src from AWS S3

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm writing a web application in Angular and I'm using AWS S3 to store images.

I need to display images in my application and have the following approach:

```
new AWS.S3().getObject({Bucket: 'very-secret-bucket', Key: uuid}, (err, data) => {
    return 'data:' + data.ContentType + ';base64,' + this.encode(data.Body)
})
```

As you can see: I get the object from S3 and converts it to a `base64` image string.

This approach is extremely slow (>5 sec for each image) on new smart phones (iPhone X).

I have tried a different approach:

```
let imgSrc = 'data:' + data.ContentType + ';base64,' + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data.Body));
```

This approach triggers a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` when images are larger than around 0.4 MB

**Question:** What's the most effective way to programmatically fetch images from S3 (or similar source)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get a signed url if your objects are private.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I looked for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you show images on the web, you can maybe consider to make the bucket public, so you can use the direct URLs of the S3 object in html rendering:

```
<img src="url-of-s3-object" ...
```

If you have to do authorization, consider the following:

One way would be to hold a list of images somewhere in a database with their pre-generated presigned URLs. This would then work in the same manner.

Last option, which comes to my mind, is to create a S3 proxy via AWS Gateway API, where you can do your auth and get URLs as well.

Both last ways would bring independency on AWS SDK (just http rest calls) and leave the image displaying to the browser, which should make performance better.